# Android graphical layout not shown in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I an very new to Android. I have tried possible solutions found on this forum but none of this working. When I am creating a project just after starting IDE that time graphical layout is visible but when creating another project layout is not visible.It is visible only after restarting the IDE. what will be the working solution.

Comment: Move to Android Studio.

Comment: What exactly is not visible? The layout xml files? Or the graphical editor for the xml files?

Comment: the graphical editor for the xml files. I have pointed it.